# ASP.NET: Getting ASPX filename

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

By convention, all my web site's .aspx files also have corresponding .css files at the same path. So, for example, Default.aspx has a file Default.css in the same directory.

I wrote an extension method to add CSS  tags to the headers of `Page` objects, and use it like this on `Page_Load`:

```
this.AddCssFileRange(new[]
{
    "Default.css",
    "../Master.css"
});
```

I'd like to replace the hardcoded "Default.css" with a method that derives this based on my CSS convention. That is, I'd like to replace it with a method that returns "Default.css" because the filename of the `Page` calling it is "Default.aspx."

How can I retrieve that "Default.aspx" filename so I can replace the extension with "css"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: `Path.ChangeExtension(Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath, ".css")`.
This will return the currently executing page, even if you called `Server.Transfer`.

Comment: A better implmentation is: System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath);

This returns just the name of the file, without including the path (unless, of course, you want the path)